# WPF Bing Maps Control slow performance

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, bing-maps

I´m quite new to WPF and to threading in WPF and have successfully implemented the bing maps control in my program. Problem is, the control takes a long time to load and slows down the program itself when opening it. The loading time has increased from about 2sec to about 20sec, which is not really acceptable.

My idea was, to load the bing maps control in a separate thread and thus not to decrease the performance. I´ve been trying to do that, but my UI keeps getting blocked by the loading process of the maps control.

Here´s an example using a Dispatcher:

```
private init()
{
    Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()
    {
        // Background thread: I would like to load the map here
        Map map = new Map();
        map.CredentialsProvider = providerKey;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                // Back to the UI thread
                // How do I assign the loaded Map to this thread?
                mapElementOnUI = map;
                mapPanel.Children.Add(mapElementOnUI);
            }));
    }
    ));
    thread.Start();

    //Load the rest of the GUI here
}
```

If I handle the Threads like that I get an InvalidOperationException (no STA-Thread). If I change the code to the following, my UI blocks while loading the maps control:

```
private init()
{
    Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()
    {
        // Background thread

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                // Back to the UI thread
                mapElementOnUI = new Map();
                mapElementOnUI.CredentialsProvider = providerKey;
                mapPanel.Children.Add(mapElementOnUI);
            }));
    }
    ));
    thread.Start();

    //Load the rest of the GUI here
}
```

I´ve also been trying to implement a solution via await and async without success. Is it possible at all to load the maps control in a separate thread? Could somebody help me out on this with a piece of code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I´ve solved this now. @user1100269 gave a good hint resolving the exception I was experiencing: thread.SetApartmentState.STA. Additionally I had to create a new Map instance in the background thread without it beeing used anywhere - I didn´t really get that, but my problem is solved now. The map is loaded in the background and doesn´t block the UI anymore. Here´s the working code for anyone interested:

```
private void init()   
{

    Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(delegate()
    {
        // Background Thread
        Map map = new Map();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(() =>
            {
                // Back to the UI Thread
                var provider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider(MyCredentials);
                mapElementOnUI = new Map();
                mapElementOnUI.CredentialsProvider = provider;
                mapPanel.Children.Add(mapElementOnUI);
                updateMapLocations();
            }));
    }
    ));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this should work. Why do you create "map" in the background an don't use it anywhere? Shouldn't "mapElementOnUI" use it instead of creating a new object?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your second example all you're doing is starting up another thread that immediately switches back to the UI thread to create a control, so that's why your UI is blocking.

As for your first example, you can't create a control on one thread and use it on another (that's not the exception you were getting.  You need to call SetApartmentState before calling Start).  So you can't create the map control on a background thread and then load it into your window created on the main thread.  This is prevented by the framework.

What you *could* do is create a separate window on its own UI thread and load the map control into that window.  This would prevent your main application window from blocking, but it would require you to manage a second application window.  Also, if you wanted objects in the main application thread and objects in the map control thread to interact with each other, you'd have to do a bunch of extra work handling cross-thread calls on both ends.  You can read about this approach [here.](http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/)

As for the map control itself, I'm not familiar with it so I don't know if there's some other way to handle or defer loading without freezing your UI.

Comment: thanks for the comment :-) It helped me out, see my answer if you´re interested...